# java swing calculator two digit

Tags: java, swing

I cannot enter two digit number to be calculator. I also cannot get the clear C operator working as well. My dot sign seems to be not working as well. The code below creates a calculator using java swing and does addition, multiplication,subtraction and divisiion of a single digit number.

```
//First the necessary packages are imported

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


/**@return a BODMAS calculator using Javax Swing and awt
 * *@author Cihan Altunok
 *@version 1
 */

//implementing ActionListener to listen to events. JFrame is also extended to add support to Swing components
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //declaring some variables to be used in our program
    JFrame guiCalculatorFrame;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JTextArea numberCalculator;
    int calculatorOpr=0;
    int currentCalculation;
    //EventQueue invokeLater is used to ensure the run method is called in the dispatch thread of the EventQueue 


    //declaring the constructor for the class

    public Calculator()
    {
        //instantiating guiCalculatorFrame
        guiCalculatorFrame=new JFrame(); 
        //the red cross sign drawn to exit the window
        guiCalculatorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiCalculatorFrame.setTitle("Calculator");
        //setting the size of the frame
        guiCalculatorFrame.setSize(400,400);
        //The setLocationRelativeTo has been set to null to center the window
        guiCalculatorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //JTextField is created to allow a set of characters to be entered
        numberCalculator=new JTextArea();
        //setting the alignment of JTextField along the RIGHT axis
        numberCalculator.setAlignmentX(JTextField.RIGHT);
        //making the textfield not editable
        numberCalculator.setEditable(false);
        //container containing the components in the north region
        guiCalculatorFrame.add(numberCalculator, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //panel is created and we will add buttons to the panel later in the program
        buttonPanel=new JPanel();
        //setting Layout to GridLayout to lay the components in a rectangular grid
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        //adding the buttons to the frame. Putting the buttons in the center
        guiCalculatorFrame.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // a following for loop is done to add the numberButtons

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            addNumberButton(buttonPanel,String.valueOf(i)); 

        }

        //next the five mathematical operators are added

        addActionButton(buttonPanel,1,"+");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,2,"-");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,3,"*");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,4,"/");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,5,"^2");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,6,"C");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,7,"^");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel,8,".");
        //equalSign Button is created
        JButton equalsSignButton=new JButton("=");
        //the action command for the equal sign button is set
        equalsSignButton.setActionCommand("=");
        equalsSignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)

            //checking if the numberCalculator field is a valid mathematical operator 

            {
                if (!numberCalculator.getText().isEmpty())
                {

                    //turning text into integer
                    int number=Integer.parseInt(numberCalculator.getText());
                    // doing a series of if statements for the list of operations
                    if (calculatorOpr==1)
                    {
                        int calculate=currentCalculation+number;
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==2)
                    {
                        int calculate=currentCalculation-number;
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==3)
                    {
                        int calculate=currentCalculation*number;
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==4)
                    {
                        int calculate=currentCalculation/number;
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==5)
                    {
                        int calculate=currentCalculation*currentCalculation;
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==6)
                    {

                        numberCalculator.setText("");

                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==7)
                    {
                        int calculate=(int) Math.sqrt(Integer.parseInt(numberCalculator.getText()));
                        numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));


                    }
                    else if (calculatorOpr==8)
                    {
                        numberCalculator.append(".");
                    }
                }

            }


        });
        //adding equals sign to the panel
        buttonPanel.add(equalsSignButton);
        //setting the visibility to True so the frame can be seen
        guiCalculatorFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
    //passing two paremeters to the addNumberButton method
    private void addNumberButton(Container contain, String name) {
        JButton buttonOne=new JButton(name);
        //setting the action command for the button created above
        buttonOne.setActionCommand(name);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(this);
        //adding buttonOne to the container
        contain.add(buttonOne);

    }
    //passing three parameters to the addActionButton method
    private void addActionButton(Container contain, int i, String text) {
        JButton buttonOne=new JButton(text);
        //setting the action command for the button created above
        buttonOne.setActionCommand(text);
        //creating a new class
        Operators addAction=new Operators(i);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(addAction);
        //adding buttonOne to the container

        contain.add(buttonOne);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        //returning the command string associated with this string
        String i=event.getActionCommand();
        //setting the Text to the specified String
        numberCalculator.setText(i);

    }

    //creating an inner class and implementing ActionListener
    private class Operators implements ActionListener
    {

        private int operators;

        //creating a constructor and passing a parameter
        public Operators(int operation)
        {
            operators=operation;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            currentCalculation=Integer.parseInt(numberCalculator.getText());
            calculatorOpr=operators;
        }


    }
}*
```

Comment: `numberCalculator.setText(i);` Well, it seems you are replacing the entire text with the label of the pressed button, so entering a second digit overwrites any prior input.

Comment: It would be better to post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem in a few lines.   Hundreds of lines of code like this make more work for the people answering the question, and make it less likely that future visitors will identify that they have the exact same problem.

Comment: I will definitely post less code next time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you were overwrting the text field. and the action listener for `C` button was wrong. This will solve your basic problems, but some work remaining. For instance you are not handling the `.` at the moment.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // declaring some variables to be used in our program
    JFrame guiCalculatorFrame;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JTextArea numberCalculator;
    int calculatorOpr = 0;
    int currentCalculation;
    boolean isOperatorActive = false;

    // EventQueue invokeLater is used to ensure the run method is called in the
    // dispatch thread of the EventQueue

    // declaring the constructor for the class

    public Calculator() {
        // instantiating guiCalculatorFrame
        guiCalculatorFrame = new JFrame();
        // the red cross sign drawn to exit the window
        guiCalculatorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiCalculatorFrame.setTitle("Calculator");
        // setting the size of the frame
        guiCalculatorFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        // The setLocationRelativeTo has been set to null to center the window
        guiCalculatorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // JTextField is created to allow a set of characters to be entered
        numberCalculator = new JTextArea();
        // setting the alignment of JTextField along the RIGHT axis
        numberCalculator.setAlignmentX(JTextField.RIGHT);
        // making the textfield not editable
        numberCalculator.setEditable(false);
        // container containing the components in the north region
        guiCalculatorFrame.add(numberCalculator, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // panel is created and we will add buttons to the panel later in the
        // program
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        // setting Layout to GridLayout to lay the components in a rectangular
        // grid
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        // adding the buttons to the frame. Putting the buttons in the center
        guiCalculatorFrame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // a following for loop is done to add the numberButtons

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addNumberButton(buttonPanel, String.valueOf(i));
        }

        // next the five mathematical operators are added

        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 1, "+");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 2, "-");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 3, "*");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 4, "/");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 5, "^2");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 6, "C");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 7, "^");
        addActionButton(buttonPanel, 8, ".");
        // equalSign Button is created
        JButton equalsSignButton = new JButton("=");
        // the action command for the equal sign button is set
        equalsSignButton.setActionCommand("=");
        equalsSignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                // checking if the numberCalculator field is a valid mathematical
                // operator
                isOperatorActive = true;
                if (!numberCalculator.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    // turning text into integer
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberCalculator.getText());
                    // doing a series of if statements for the list of
                    // operations
                    int calculate = 0;
                    switch (calculatorOpr) {
                        case 1:
                            calculate = currentCalculation + number;
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            calculate = currentCalculation - number;
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            calculate = currentCalculation * number;
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            calculate = currentCalculation / number;
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            calculate = currentCalculation * currentCalculation;
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            calculate = (int) Math.sqrt(Integer
                                    .parseInt(numberCalculator.getText()));
                            numberCalculator.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            numberCalculator.append(".");
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        // adding equals sign to the panel
        buttonPanel.add(equalsSignButton);
        // setting the visibility to True so the frame can be seen
        guiCalculatorFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    // passing two parameters to the addNumberButton method
    private void addNumberButton(Container contain, String name) {
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton(name);
        // setting the action command for the button created above
        buttonOne.setActionCommand(name);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(this);
        // adding buttonOne to the container
        contain.add(buttonOne);
    }

    // passing three parameters to the addActionButton method
    private void addActionButton(Container contain, int i, String text) {
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton(text);
        // setting the action command for the button created above
        buttonOne.setActionCommand(text);
        // creating a new class
        Operators addAction = new Operators(i);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(addAction);
        // adding buttonOne to the container

        contain.add(buttonOne);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // returning the command string associated with this string
        String i = event.getActionCommand();
        // setting the Text to the specified String
        if(isOperatorActive){
            numberCalculator.setText(i);
            isOperatorActive = false;
        } else {
            numberCalculator.setText(numberCalculator.getText() + i);
        }
    }

    // creating an inner class and implementing ActionListener
    private class Operators implements ActionListener {

        private int operators;

        // creating a constructor and passing a parameter
        public Operators(int operation) {
            operators = operation;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            isOperatorActive = true;
            switch (operators) {
                case 6:
                    numberCalculator.setText("");
                    currentCalculation = 0;
                    calculatorOpr = 0;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    isOperatorActive = false;
                default:
                    currentCalculation = Integer.parseInt(numberCalculator.getText());
                    calculatorOpr = operators;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
/*
@ Author 12CSE54
@ Date 29.10.14
*/
    public class calculator1 extends JFrame
     {
        public calculator1() {
            initComponents();
        }

    int a,b,c;
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    c=a+b;
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    c=a-b;
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    c=a*b;
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    c=a/b;
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(c));

    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    }                                        

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new calculator1().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
```